# UserControl in DataTemplate does not bind correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls

I've been trying to create a custom menu. For this reason I wanted to use an ItemsControl in order to make it flexible. After hours of headache I figured out how to make it - kinda.

I have my custom ItemsControl "LiftMenu" (which is not yet much custom but standard) and an UserControl called "LiftItem". Last but not least I got the Model-class "LiftMenuItem".

By adding a new LiftMenuItem to the LiftMenu, it should display a new LiftItem-control as corresponding item. So far so good, I managed to get this working.

In that LiftItem-control I bind like I would in a normal DataTemplate: plain bindings with a path, nothing more. Normally this would work just fine because the DataTemplate already has it's context set to the model-type.

But now I just get an empty control that does nothing and shows nothing, because the bindings don't work.

I implemented it this way:

```
<menu:LiftMenu HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="200" Background="#80A8A8A8" Margin="5,0,0,0">
<menu:LiftMenu.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</menu:LiftMenu.ItemsPanel>
<menu:LiftMenu.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type menu:LiftMenuItem}">
        <menu:LiftItem />
    </DataTemplate>
</menu:LiftMenu.ItemTemplate>
<menu:LiftMenuItem Header="Test1"/>
```

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{Binding LabelColor}" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="4" Background="{Binding BorderBrush, ElementName=border}"/>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Margin="5,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Foreground="White" />

    <controls:ProgressRing x:Name="ring" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Stroke="#ffff8000" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding ProcessValue}" IsIndeterminate="{Binding ProcessIndeterminate}" Visibility="{Binding ProcessVisibility}"
        Width="20" Height="20" Radius="10" Margin="2,0,2,0" />
</Grid>
```

In the end there is no text, no border. Just the ProgressRing is visible.

How can I fix this? This ListItem-control should become similiar to a button, thus I need to do some styling (animation, ...). I can't do this within a normal DataTemplate, but I don't want to miss the binding features of WPF on that. This would make it relatively unflexible.

What's the problem? I probably just miss some DataContext or so, but I don't know what it would be.

Comment: Apparently you forgot to set `Grid.Column="1"` on the TextBlock. Also `BorderBrush="{Binding LabelColor}"` looks dubious. Is LabelColor really a Brush?

Comment: Once again errors after long programming sessions. You're right. I changed this "by accident" a few minutes back and was astonished that it worked suddenly. But thanks for the hint, I overlooked that LabelColor must be of type SolidColorBrush.